# notify an app when a new row added in a specific table in oracle

Tags: java, oracle

i need a way to notify an java app when new row added in table to do some jobs and run a query.

**i tried to use qcn but it gives error that my db isnt support it and i dont think it is what i needed**.

***i dont want write a program that periodicly (i dont know if its a correct word! :D )  run the query.***

the query should be run when a new row added.
i googled and i searched ask tom it but no luck.
the database is oracle and i want to write app in java.
**tnx in advance.**

Comment: Look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17599155/sending-a-jms-message-from-oracle-database-on-dml-event

Comment: Consider [Continuous Query Notification](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/JJDBC/dbchgnf.htm#JJDBC28815)

Comment: @krokodilko i want to use it. and i mentioned it in my question that my db probebly doesnt support it!
my problem is i should develope an app that can work with different oracle db version.

Comment: @alireza the documentation states that `This code will also work with Oracle Database 10g Release 2 (10.2)`, so 3 versions of Oracle Database are supported. If you are using Oracle 9 or earlier then consider an upgrade, version 9 is 15 years old.

Answer (score 1):

try to use "Database Change Notification"

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/java.112/e16548/dbchgnf.htm#JJDBC28815